# Re-using PowerShell session with WinRM

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

My overall goal is to initialize a powershell session once, invoke some commands over time and finally close the session. I need to call powershell via winrm. Since I'm developing a Java application, I use winrm4j to invoke shell commands via winrm.

The motivation behind keeping the ps session open is that I am accessing Exchange Online via `Connect-ExchangeOnline` cmdlet. Unfortunately, this is taking about 10 seconds and to save time I would like to re-use the ps session for several commands like `Get-Mailbox` etc instead of connecting to Exchange Online every time I invoke an Exchange cmdlet.

This is my pseudo-powershell code I am executing. For now, I am running against my local machine:

- Starting the session:

```
$s = New-PSSession -Name mysession -ComputerName . -Authentication Basic -Credential ...
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { <# here comes Exchange online initialization #> }
Disconnect-PSSession -Session $s
```

- Invoking a command:

```
$rs = Get-PSSession -Name mysession -ComputerName . -Authentication Basic -Credential ...
Connect-PSSession -Session $s
Enter-PSSession -Session $s
<# run the actual Exchange cmdlet #>
Exit-PSSession
Disconnect-PSSession -Session $s
```

- Cleanup:

```
$rs = Get-PSSession -Name mysession -ComputerName . -Authentication Basic -Credential ...
Remove-PSSession -Session $rs
```

When I manually do this, I can run a `Get-Mailbox` and get a proper result. **However**, when I run it programmatically, it doesn't work. An error is returned that `Get-Mailbox` couldn't be found as cmdlet. And also other variables from the initialization or not available.

What makes the difference here via winrm?

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` is for _interactive use_ only - for an unattended script, use `Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {<# exchange cmdlet invocations go here #>}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen True, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mathias pointed out in the comments, the solution is to use `Invoke-Command` instead of `Enter-PSSession` as it is for interactive session only. Unfortunately, there is no error message or similar when calling `Enter-PSSession` via winrm programmatically.